# Wi-Fi Not Working in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: wireless

When I turn on the computer, the Wi-Fi doesn't work, but this doesn't happen all the time. Sometimes it starts up without any issues, and other times the Wi-Fi doesn't work. If it's not working, I restart the computer, and the problem is resolved, but this situation is very inconvenient. What should I do?

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsmod| grep cfg; lsusb

    00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:43f0] (rev 11)
        DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz [8086:0074]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
--
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
        Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [152d:1360]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
snd_intel_dspcfg       32768  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
cfg80211             1314816  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0408:5050 Quanta Computer, Inc. USB HD Webcam
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:a09f Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. E-Signal LUOM G10 Mechanical Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsmod| grep cfg; lsusb` Is Windows also installed?

Comment: Yes, I've both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Is hybrid shutdown disabled in Windows?  It can cause problems with wifi in Linux if it is enabled

Comment: I recently installed 23.10; everything worked superbly for about a week.. then BANG! I can no longer connect to Internet(via Wi-Fi).  it's not the hardware because I can connect to Internet using my startup USB on same machine.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I don't even know what a hybrid shutdown is :/ How can I check it?

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001762.htm  https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-turn-on-or-off-fast-startup/